# Accessible React combobox

Tags: javascript, react.js

To learn React I've ported a Vue combobox component into React. Because of the project it could be used in uses React 16.2 it doesn't use features like `React.createRef()` or hooks.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

class ComboBox extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      active: 0,
      shown: false,
      value: props.value
    }

    this.root = null
    this.textbox = null
    this.options = new Array(props.items.length)

    this.setRootRef = element => this.root = element
    this.setTextboxRef = element => this.textbox = element
    this.setOptionsRef = (index, element) => this.options[index] = element

    this.listenForClickOut = this.listenForClickOut.bind(this)
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    this.handleTextboxKeypress = this.handleTextboxKeypress.bind(this)
    this.handleListboxKeypress = this.handleListboxKeypress.bind(this)
    this.handleRootKeydown = this.handleRootKeydown.bind(this)
  }

  get items () {
    return this.props.items
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    window.addEventListener('click', this.listenForClickOut)
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    window.removeEventListener('click', this.listenForClickOut)
  }

  /* Event handlers */

  listenForClickOut (click) {
    if (!this.root.contains(click.target)) {
      this.hide()
    }
  }

  handleChange (event) {
    this.setState({
      value: event.target.value,
    })
  }

  handleTextboxKeypress (event) {
    switch (event.key) {
      case 'ArrowDown':
        this.open()
        break
    }
  }

  async handleListboxKeypress (event) {
    switch (event.key) {
      case 'ArrowUp':
        await this.up()
        break
      case 'ArrowDown':
        await this.next()
        this.focusOption()
        break
    }
  }

  handleRootKeydown (event) {
    switch (event.key) {
      case 'Tab':
      case 'Escape':
        this.close()
        break
    }
  }

  handleClick (i) {
    this.props.onSelect(this.items[i])
    this.close()
  }

  /* Position methods */

  first () {
    this.setState({
      active: 0
    })
  }

  previous () {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      const previous = this.state.active - 1
      if (previous >= 0) {
        this.setState({
          active: previous
        }, resolve)
      }
    })
  }

  next () {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      const max = this.items.length - 1
      const next = this.state.active + 1
      if (next <= max) {
        this.setState({
          active: next
        }, resolve)
      }
    })
  }

  /* List control methods */

  async open () {
    if (this.items.length === 0) {
      return
    }
    this.first()
    await this.show()
    this.focusOption()
  }

  close () {
    this.hide()
    this.focusTextbox()
  }

  show () {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.setState({
        shown: true
      }, resolve)
    })
  }

  hide () {
    this.setState({
      shown: false
    })
  }

  async up () {
    if (this.state.active === 0) {
      this.close()
      return
    }

    await this.previous()
    this.focusOption()
  }

  async down () {
    await this.next()
    this.focusOption()
  }

  focusTextbox () {
    this.textbox.focus()
  }

  focusOption () {
    const index = this.state.active
    this.options[index].focus()
  }

  render () {
    const { items } = this.props
    const { active, shown, value } = this.state

    return (
      <div ref={this.setRootRef} onKeyDown={this.handleRootKeydown}>
        <input
          aria-autocomplete="list"
          aria-expanded={shown}
          autoComplete="off"
          autoCapitalize="none"
          className="form-control"
          ref={this.setTextboxRef}
          role="combobox"
          value={value}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          onKeyDown={this.handleTextboxKeypress}
        />
        {shown &&
        <div className="list-group" role="listbox" onKeyDown={this.handleListboxKeypress}>
          {items.map((item, i) => (
            <button
              aria-selected={active === i}
              className={`list-group-item list-group-item-action py-1 ${active === i ? 'active' : ''}`}
              key={i}
              ref={element => this.setOptionsRef(i, element)}
              role="option"
              tabIndex="-1"
              onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)}
            >
              {item}
            </button>
          ))}
        </div>
        }
        <div aria-live="polite" role="status" className="sr-only">{items.length} results available.</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ComboBox.propTypes = {
  items: PropTypes.array,
  value: PropTypes.string,
  onSelect: PropTypes.func,
}
ComboBox.defaultProps = {
  items: [],
  value: '',
  onSelect: () => ({})
}

export default ComboBox
```

[Demo on codepen](https://codepen.io/jmsfwk/full/dyGoZPz)